# Div class min-width still resizing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Good day, so i have a login function encased in a div tag. I would just like to freeze the div if i resize. I tried adding min-width and display: inline-block but its still resizing. Any help would be appreciated. Also, using a pixel value still wont work.

[image]

the screenshot shows that min-width:300% !important; did not work.

I also placed my code in JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wvhgsek9/

HTML:

```
  <form class="reg_log_box login_box form-group">
        <br>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>EMAIL</p>
            <input type="text" placeholder="EMAIL" autocomplete="off" name="email"
            value="<?php
              if(isset($_POST["email"])) {
                echo($_POST["email"]);
              } ?>">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>PASSWORD</p>
            <input type="text" placeholder="PASSWORD" autocomplete="off" name="password">
          </div>
        </div>
          <input type="submit" id="login" name="login" value="LOGIN" class="reg_signup">
          <p class="center_font">NO ACCOUNT YET? <a href="register.php">REGISTER HERE</a></p>
        <br>
    </form>
```

CSS:

```
.login_box {
      min-width: 30% !important;
      display: inline-block
    }

    .reg_log_box {
      width: 50%;
      padding: 10px 70px 10px;
      background: #fff;
      opacity: 0.9;
      border-radius: 30px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
.login_box {
  min-width: 30% !important;
  display: inline-block
}
```

Is not going to work because that will mean to resize the box always to 30% of what ever the browser window's width is.

Instead, supply a pixel based value e.g.

```
.login_box {
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

Edit:

To fully stop resizing completely then change your width to a pixel based value.

```
.reg_log_box {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px 70px 10px;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0.9;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You can then remove `.login_box` css all together...

Comment: forgot to mention a pixel value still does not prevent it from resizing

Comment: yes like i said i switched it to pixels but its still resizing the same way as the image i uploaded

Comment: @HadrianClayton Did you also removed the `display: inline-block` part? That is the issue here.

Comment: It definitely does not resize when I put it in the fiddle, it stays at the specified width.

Comment: I added a border to the body, notice how the button/text etc does not shrink in width but rather moves off screen since it can't be resized. https://jsfiddle.net/wvhgsek9/1/

Comment: i just took out the inline-block, thanks for the tip, I wont get confused on resizing in the future.

Comment: @HadrianClayton Feel free to accept my answer by hitting the check mark next to the vote arrows :)

Answer (score 0):

try `resize: block;`

block
    The element displays a mechanism for allowing the user to resize it in the block direction (either horizontally or vertically, depending on the writing-mode and direction value).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize

Comment: resize-block does not change it

Comment: `overflow:auto;
display:inline-block;`

Comment: sorry its still the same

Comment: try it with maxwidth maxHeight height and width defined by pixel value, those with display:inline-block may work now